# In an interface what should I use a try-catch or throws for each method?

Tags: java, interface

```
public interface RMIInterface extends Remote {
    public byte[] geScreen() throws RemoteException;
    public byte[] getProcessList() throws RemoteException;
    public boolean execute(String command) throws RemoteException;
    public boolean messageTo(String msg,String user) throws RemoteException;
    public boolean saveImage(byte[] image,String user) throws RemoteException;
    public byte[][] getimages(String user,String date)throws RemoteException;
}
```

The above RMI interface methods throws RemoteException, is it ok if I enclose these methods in a try, and catch the RemoteException.

Comment: how do you use try catch in an interface? Can you show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use try-catch in interfaces because there is no implementation here, only specification/contracting. On the contrary you could use `throws <exception list>` as you've already done.

Answer (score 2):

calling these methods in a `try-catch` block means that you are handling the exception in the same method itselft. On the contrary, if you use `throws` declaration for the method, then it say this method can `throw` this type of exception, technically ducking that exception and that exception needs to be handled by the method which calls that method.

In case of interface

- Whatever methods you write in the interface are `public` and `abstract`
- For writing `try-catch` you must provide implementation of the method and in case of interface you can't do that.
- So even  if you desperately want to write `try-catch` in an interface, you can't do it :)

It is upto you if you want to handle the exceptions in the same method or make the calling method handle it.

This is the example of a method handling an exception

```
public static void methodWithNoThrows(){
    try{
        throw new Exception();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is the example of a method ducking and exception by declaring throws

```
 public static void methodWithThrows() throws Exception{

    throw new Exception();
}
```

So the calling method has to handle it

Answer (score 2):

The remote interface methods in RMI should throw `RemoteException`. These exception have to be caught by the Client which is calling the methods declared by the remote interface.

An interface on itself cannot catch the exception thrown by the methods declared in it.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces by themselves are not instantiable (or have method bodies, not until default methods), and thus cannot have try-catch blocks.

However, consider what you're declaring here:  every method in this interface now has a checked exception.  If you intend to, in the running of this code, actively *catch* the exception(s) that could be thrown, then there is no value added to declaring those methods as throwing anything.  On the other hand, if you want to be explicit in that the code using this API catches any exceptions on *its* end, then this would be acceptable.